# Dynamically setting content in Geb

Tags: xpath, groovy, geb

I want to define a method in a groovy class that I can pass an xpath to on the fly(in order for the same method to be reusable depending on the application). The code snippet below is just a proof of concept, however I would eventually like to build a library of re-usable commands/components, which is why I would like to learn how to dynamically define page content.

If I try this:

```
import geb.Page;


class oneStepDefMethodClass extends Page {
static url = 'http://www.google.com'
static content = {
    queryInput { $("input", id: "gbqfq") }   
    queryButton { $("button",name: "btnG") } 
    //songLink { $("span._BZ")} 
}
....
void assertSongInResults2(String xpathOfSongLink){
    println "Waiting on video link "+ xpathOfSongLink

     songLink { $(xpathOfSongLink)}

    waitFor {
        songLink.displayed
    }
}

}
```

I get this error :groovy.lang.MissingMethodException: No signature of method: geb.navigator.NonEmptyNavigator.songLink() is applicable for argument types: (oneStepDefMethodClass$_assertSongInResults2_closure3) values: [oneStepDefMethodClass$_assertSongInResults2_closure3@7c455e96]

If I throw a

```
content={songLink {$(xpathOfSongLink)}
}
```

block in the assertSongInResults2 method, I get this error:
geb.error.UnresolvablePropertyException: Unable to resolve songLink as content for oneStepDefMethodClass, or as a property on its Navigator context. Is songLink a class you forgot to import?

So, yeah is there a way to dynamically define page content like that? The program executes fine if I define it statically up top with the rest of the content , but that is not the point, I want to create re-usable resources instead of redefining the wheel every time I want to use geb.

Answer (score 2):

Solved as I was writing the question, but thought I would post in case anyone else has a similar problem

```
static String someXpath

static content = {
    queryInput { $("input", id: "gbqfq") } //  
    queryButton { $("button",name: "btnG") } //
    songLink { $(someXpath) } //syntax element.className

}
....
    void assertSongInResults2(String xpathOfSongLink){
    println "Waiting on video link "+ xpathOfSongLink
    someXpath=xpathOfSongLink
    waitFor {
        songLink.displayed
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for sharing the answer! After 48 hours, you can even [accept your own answer](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2009/01/accept-your-own-answers/) to prevent the question from appearing in the "unanswered" tab.